# "Should both 'subjects' conform" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, subordinate-clauses

I got the sentence from a recipe book titled ............................... by ....................

> Pour the sugar into the milk **while on the fire.**

Here the **subjects** of the two **clauses** do not seem to conform.

As a learner I suppose it might have been:

> ...while **the milk is / it is** on the fire.

To me, otherwise it seems like:

> (You) pour the sugar into the milk **while you are on the fire.**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which recipe book? Please give a clear and exact source.  It is not very idiomatic to use "on the fire" for cooking on a regular hob.

Comment: @JamesK I apologize for digression but would you suggest me any source that would help me with "providing a link to stackexchange." I have a lot of issues specifying to my best. I am all prepared to remove this comment if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Edit the question. Select the word or phrase. Press the link button (looks like a sloping 8, its meant to be a two links in a chain) A window opens. You copy the URL and press ok.

Comment: "Pour ... while on the fire" sounds like a hot cook.

Comment: An example of grammatical ambiguity. But in these cases you have to figure out the implied meaning.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 ambiguity or mistake?